# Mongoose getting newly saved object id off by one

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using the latest version of mongoose.

```
var question = new CodingQuestion(reqJSON);
question.save(function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else{
        var questionId = question.id;
        console.log("successfully added question with id", questionId);
    }
});
```

The new object can be saved successfully. The problem is that when I try to obtain the newly added object Id, the value I get is always off by one. For example, the value logged in console is "5356b2162f8a71c00ae48783" but the actual value in the database is "5356b2162f8a71c00ae48784". 
Any idea what may cause this problem?

Comment: Hmmm... MongoDB's id has '_id' key, not just 'id'. It seems that you receive 'id' with reqJSON so that question.id does not return undefined. Try to util.inspect question after it is saved. Or even better question._doc to omit unnecessary mongoose's stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not getting the *ID* of the saved document. The anonymous function you pass the  `save` function takes two parameters, `error` and `saved_document`.

Try the following:

```
question.save(function(err, savedQuestion) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else{
        var questionId = savedQuestion._id;
        console.log("successfully added question with id", questionId);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is what I tried before. Both methods produce the same result. The id value I get is always smaller (by 1) than the actual value in the database.

Comment: Try to `console.log(savedQuestion)`, not just the `id` property. The `_ID` from mongodb _should_ be in there.

Comment: There might be something wrong with mongo in my terminal. If I retrieve from database and display the data, I get the same id's as logged in console. The only problem is that mongo displays differently. Both id and _id works. Even my old code works. Thanks for helping. :)

Answer (score 0):

We just ran into this issue.  When you use the `new` operator it will create an objectID in mongoose.  This is ignored when you call `.save()` where it will then use the next available objectID, hence it is off by one.